# CakePHP Upgrade via Rector, functions with input type array declaration

Tags: cakephp-3.5, phpstan

I'm trying to use rector (https://github.com/rectorphp/rector) for the first time to upgrade my CakePHP application.  I'm working in a local development environment first.

I've hit a bit of a headache.  For example purposes I created the following simple php class:

```
<?php

class test {
    public function init( array $data) {
       return $data;
    }
}
```

I run the following command:

```
vendor/bin/rector process src/Model/Table/test.php --level cakephp35 --dry-run
```

I receive the following error:

```
Class array was not found while trying to analyse it - autoloading is probably 
not configured properly.
```

The issue is with the "array" type declaration for the input variable in the function.  I remove it, the code passes the rector test.

I've googled around and can't find anything, which makes me think I missed something incredibly simple.  Any help?

Comment: You'd be better served by asking this in Rector issues on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you.  I did that just after I posted here.  The developer stated this was in fact a bug and has released a fix.

Comment: Rector author here... all good now?